# How does one go about developing the sound of a language for a particular culture in a world?

Tags: society, language, conlang

In Worldbuilding, linguistica communication within and between cultures can greatly affect how the world is shaped.

How does one make an invented language's aesthetic qualities *sound* authentic as regards the shapes of words, written patterns, and other phonemic relationships between dialects and related langauges?

Relatedly, is there a some sort of boilerplate or template that beginners can use as a phonetic reference?

Comment: I think this would be better on Linguistics.stackechange.com

Comment: @Styphon I suspect it might as well, but even if it is on topic here (and it very well might be! About to put it to meta), this question is *way* too broad. There's almost no hope of finding a One True Way to accomplish this. This question would be far better posed as "How do I develop a language for *this culture* in a part of my world that's like *this*?"

Comment: I borrowed a portion of this question: [When designing a language for an intelligent species, how to decide on phonemes?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/58/29)

Comment: Tried to focus the question on overall sound & aesthetics: can it be reopened?

Comment: This would be good for Constructed Languages.SE. You can also put it in the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), which is a better option than meta. Meta is about the Worldbuilding site, the Sandbox is to help improve questions.

Comment: Of course, the question was originally asked long before CL.SE was even conceived of. How can the question be transderred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just starting out, I would recommend selecting a number of phonemes (sounds) for each language to have, as well as rules for what sounds can be arranged in what ways (this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0h-gbeI0AFQ can help with that).

As far as making them sound authentic, one suggestion is: don't make all the languages have Indo-European syntax. The other videos on the channel I linked to talk about that some.

For dialects, you could swap out one or two phonemes for similar ones, as well as having different words for a variety of things while keeping the syntax and grammar the same.

The appendices of Lord of the Rings are always a great place to look for tips on constructing languages.